# Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, wamp

I had install wamp on my win10 computer and when i start it, i get this error

> 2017-07-03 14:42:06 8324 [ERROR] wampmysqld: Can't create/write to
> file 'c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\COM2.pid' (Errcode: 13 -
> Permission denied)
>
> 2017-07-03 14:42:06 8324 [ERROR] Can't start
> server: can't create PID file: Permission denied

Comment: Well, isn't the error statement crystal clear?

Comment: Try stopping WAMPServer, deleting the COM2.pid file and then restart WAMPServer. Also, make sure you are starting WAMPServer as Administrator

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have persmission to write to: c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data
Either logon with an administrator account or give persmission to write to this folder.